# sign up and sign in form in same view. django (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-views

I want sign up and sign in form in same page. at home page default is sign up view but when click sign in button i want fadeout (js) sign up form and fade in sign in form.

i have this error--->>>

**local variable 'form1' referenced before assignment**

```
def regform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUp(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
    if request.method=='POST' and 'log' in request.POST:
        form1=AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid():
            return redirect('/')   
        else:
            form1=AuthenticationForm()

    else:
        form = SignUp()

    return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'form': form,'form1':form1})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 **Try This**
 def regform(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = SignUp(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
                user = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/')
        if request.method=='POST' and 'log' in request.POST:
            form1=AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
            if form1.is_valid():
                return redirect('/')   
            else:
                form1=AuthenticationForm()
    
        form = SignUp()
        form1 = AuthenticationForm()
    
        return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'form': form,'form1':form1})
```